# Is there a good way to parse C# 3.0 code?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I've been looking for a free (as in "free beer") library that can parse C# 3.0 code (actually, C# 2.0 with lambdas would do it) and return some sort of AST/code DOM for a personal project. However, most alternatives I've seen up to now are inadequate:

- `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider.Parse` throws a `NotImpementedException`;
- [Visual Studio's "exposed" code parser sucks](http://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/archive/2003/12/02/40641.aspx);
- The ways of Mono's C# compiler are impenetrable (and next to not documented);
- The [C# Parser project at CodePlex](http://csparser.codeplex.com/) only parses C# 2.0 code and thus we forget lambdas;
- Another project on SourceForge [claims to parse C# to CodeDOM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cscodedomparser/), but it's 2000 days old so I guess it's not C# 3.0;
- ... and it goes on for several pages of Google results.

So... is there a free, working C# 3.0 parser out there, that can be plugged into another project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had good luck with NRefactory, written in C# and used for the SharpDevelop IDE written for Mono:

http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/NRefactory.ashx

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://antlrcsharp.codeplex.com/ 
It is a C# 4 grammar for the Antlr parser generator.

Comment: Interesting, I'll see what it does.

Comment: Do you know if there are examples available somewhere?

Comment: Take a look at the project unit test code: http://antlrcsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/53069#421907.

Comment: They `#if` out the part about getting an AST, and activating this part instead triggers a compile error. :/